# Is American Express widely accepted in France?

Tags: france, payment-cards

I'm going to be in France — mainly cities, especially Paris and Brest — for about a month this summer and the only credit card I have without ridiculous foreign fees is AMEX. How much can I count on this being accepted?

If I got a VISA or MasterCard, would I have better acceptance?

Comment: Not sure about France per se, but from what I've seen across Europe AMEX is barely accepted at all. This is because of their excessive fees. You as a holder may have lower fees, but the retailer accepting it pays through the nose...

Comment: Off-topic, but you can get cards that have much lower fees, such as from fintech companies (I use a Transferwise Borderless debit Mastercard, there are others)

Comment: @gerrit As far as I know, the Transferwise card is only available to EU residents at the moment, not US residents. Though I realise we don't actually know where OP is residing.

Comment: @jcaron: I am from the US.

Comment: My Capitol One Visa doesn't have foreign currency transaction fees...

Comment: Revolut as an alternative maybe?

Comment: @jwenting That's precisely why I love my Amex. ;) But seriously, every American should have a Visa or a Mastercard (preferrably at least one of each) *and* an Amex. They're useful for different purposes.

Comment: You sure your specific amex doesn't have foreign fees? There are very few that don't (and afaict for every amex with a fee is 2.7%, which is not great though slightly better than the pretty common 3%).

Comment: @Kevin I personally have 3 Amex cards with no foreign transaction fees. There are lots of them in the U.S. There are an increasingly large number of Visa and Mastercard card products with no FTFs here, too. And no Discover cards have FTFs. FTFs generally seem to be on the way out in the U.S.

Comment: Note that there are several possible fees: a foreign transaction fee, a currency exchange fee (both of which can be fixed and/or a percentage, possibly with min/max amounts), and a spread on the currency exchange rate. The latter is the least visible but probably the most frequent.

Comment: Note that, whatever card you are using, many shops in France would be unhappy/would refuse small amounts paid with cards and ask for cash.

Comment: Is American Express widely accepted anywhere?

Comment: When going to France, the answer is always cash. Just take enough with you and don't store it all in once place.

Comment: @jwenting I live in London and use Amex for 95% of my purchases, so not sure “barely accepted” is correct.

Comment: @ThomasEdwards in both the Netherlands, Germany, and Spain where I've been in recent years AMEX is barely accepted if at all. In fact most places that do accept credit cards at all accept only Mastercard and/or Visa (and not all of them accept even both of those).

Answer (score 45):

For both historical and financial reasons, American Express acceptance in France is quite low.

Visa and MasterCard were associated from the start with the CB program, so anywhere they take cards they will take Visa and MasterCard, it's a standard part of the contract a merchant would get from their bank for card acceptance.

On the other hand, American Express acceptance often needs to be requested separately, and the fees are often much higher, so merchants often don't bother.

American Express cards will be accepted in most upscale hotels, restaurants and shops (mostly those that cater to high-end tourists), but other than that, it's pretty much a lottery.

American Express have been working hard to expand acceptance, so you can have some nice surprises. They are actually accepted in stores like Carrefour (though not the very small ones) or Monoprix.

They have a site where you can look up merchants which will accept AmEx: https://www.americanexpress.com/fr-FR/maps

As a side note, even if the stores accepts contactless payments and American Express, it's nearly impossible to find a place where you can use American Express with contactless or Apple Pay, the terminals are usually not configured correctly for this.

You will most likely need to have a Visa or MasterCard card, or use cash, in most places. Note also that ATMs that allow you to make withdrawals (cash advances) on American Express are quite rare as well.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94279/discussion-on-answer-by-jcaron-is-american-express-widely-accepted-in-france).

Answer (score 23):

I am in France for business and personal...   Can only use my AMEX when I am in a very obvious "business" situation.   Hotels fine (maybe not cheap ones).   Restaurants near business districts usually OK but still not 100%.   Random restaurant maybe 25% if that.

Shops are hit and miss.   A high-end store might accept AMEX 60-70% but a mom and pop might be 10% - again usually only if they are in a business district or near a hotel with business travelers.

In Paris I can use my AMEX 80% of the time in the financial district and about 20% of the time in other parts.   So the answer is if you are only bringing an AMEX you better bring tons of cash.

Answer (score 4):

It's well worth paying the 'ridiculous' fees for a Mastercard or Visa card.  Or at least searching for a reasonable one; they exist.

American Express is basically only accepted in tourist traps, places where you'd expect some visiting American to wander into with their business expenses.  Not exactly the best way to spend a vacation in France, and also very hard to find outside of Paris.

Comment: In France, for the cardholder, there is no difference between a Visa and a MasterCard. Both are integrated into the CB network, all merchants accept both, all ATMs accept both. There are however differences when it comes to Visa Electron or Maestro, which are different beasts.

Answer (score 3):

I'm French  and I have both. There are no problems using Visa anywhere. Because of transaction fees, some shops may not accept American Express cards.

In big cities you won't have any problem with your American Express card but in a small village I am not so sure.

Contactless payment is becoming more popular but having a Visa or Mastercard would be preferable. Have a nice trip.

You can try asking (before shopping): *Prenez-vous les AMEX ou seulement visacard?* (do you accept AMEX or only Visa cards?)

Comment: Please try to write in complete sentences.

Comment: It's worth noting that even if a merchant accepts ISO/IEC 14443 contactless payments, they can still accept Visa/Mastercard but not American Express.

Comment: Or, instead of asking, watch out for the respective stickers at the entrance doors.

Comment: @glglgl - those aren't always accurate especially in respect to American Express.

Answer (score 2):

> How much can I count on this being accepted?

Some places would accept them however certainly nowhere as widely accepted as in the USA. I used my AMEX for dining when I visited. Always prudent to have some cash, especially for smaller establishments and hole-in-the-wall locations.

> If I got a VISA or MasterCard, would I have better acceptance?

Absolutely

### TL;DR

I am extremely surprised you indicate you could only find American Express cards without foreign transaction fees because there must be at least five times as many Visa/MasterCard cards without transaction fees as American Express cards.

Comment: OP was talking about the cards he currently has, not those he could potentially get.

Comment: I have a number of cards, but this one just happens to be the only one with no international fees. I can see about getting a VISA or MC with a similar benefit.